# If statement causes page not to load

Tags: php, html

I have a switch (checkboxes) and when $checkedans = true then flip the switch to checked else leave default (unchecked).

The error is when i try load the page it just goes white screen.

The switch and all works perfectly without the php inside but i need the if statement. Anyone know why this is happening / know a fix?

My code:

```
echo"
                <td class=\"alarmvalue\" style=\"padding:2px 15px;\">
                    <label class=\"switch-lightp2 well_\" onchange=\"checkSelectedScheduleType()\">";
                        if ($checkedans == true) {
                                echo "<input id=\"radioSelected\" name=\"radioSelected\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" checked>\n"
                            }else{
                                echo "<input id=\"radioSelected\" name=\"radioSelected\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\">\n";
                            } 
                echo"   <span><span>keep</span><span>remove</span></span><a class=\"btn btn-primary\"></a>
                    </label>
                </td> "
```

Comment: Get rid of mixing PHP and HTML. This would be my fix for all of your dev issues ;)

Comment: You're missing semicolons.

Comment: You're missing some semicolons and I wouldn't compare boolean values, just do `if($checkedans)`

Comment: Please use Netbeans or else as coding tool. Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the first line of your script while developing.

Comment: @irishwill200 Look at the end of each line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to a missing semicolon.

On line:

```
echo "<input id=\"radioSelected\" name=\"radioSelected\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" checked>\n"
```

Should be:

```
echo "<input id=\"radioSelected\" name=\"radioSelected\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" checked>\n";
```

Comment: Activate error messages.